Help finding the the mapping form the z-plane to the w-plane of the unit circle.
Here is the question:

A mapping from the $z$-plane to the $w$-plane, where $w = u + iv$, is given by:
$$w = \frac{z - 1}{z + i}$$
The unit circle in the $z$ plane maps to which of the following in the $w$-plane?
(a) a circle with centre $(0,1)$ and radius $1$
(b) the diagonal line $u = v$
(c) the vertical line $u = -1$
(d) the horizontal line $v = i$
(e) none of the above

So far I have tried two methods, first substituting in $z = x + iy$, then finding $u$ and $v$, I got to:
$$
u = \frac{x^2 + y^2 -x +  y}{x^2 + (y + 1)^2} \quad \text{and} \quad v = \frac{-x + y + 1}{x^2 + (y + 1)^2}
$$
From then on, I am not sure what to do. I am aware of two things:

$x^2 + y^2 = 1$ - the unit circle
We are working with a Mobius Transformation, hence the unit circle should map to either a circle or a line.

The only thing I spotted is that if we let $x^2 + y^2 = 1$:
$$
u = \frac{1 + y -x}{x^2 + (y + 1)^2} \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{1 + y - x}{x^2 + (y + 1)^2}
$$
This results with us having $u = v$, and perhaps answer $(b)$? But whether it is correct or not, I am very confused about the train of thought/what is the right way of thinking about this problem.
Any reference/explanation about the theory would be greatly appreciated!

How much do you know about the geometry of Möbius transformations? To start with, are you familiar with the characterization of the reciprocal map $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z}$ as composition of circle inversion across the standard unit circle, given by $z \mapsto \frac{z}{|z|^2}$, with the reflection across the real axis, given by conjugation $z \mapsto \bar{z}$?

$1\to(0,0)$, $i\to(\frac12,\frac12)$, $-1\to(1,1)$... So, you are right.
